# What does the word "loop" mean in Actor example of GPars?

Tags: groovy, gpars

In the following [HelloWorld GPars example](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/gettingStarted.html#gettingStarted_aHelloWorldExample) we have the word `loop`:

```
def decryptor = actor {
    loop {
        react { message ->
            if (message instanceof String) reply message.reverse()
            else stop()
        }
    }
}

def console = actor {
    decryptor.send 'lellarap si yvoorG'
    react {
        println 'Decrypted message: ' + it
        decryptor.send false
    }
}

[decryptor, console]*.join()
```

How to be definitely sure, what is it? If I `Ctrl click` it in `IntelliJ` I get nothing. Simultaneously, if I `Ctrl click` the work `react`, go to [the method react in GPars](http://gpars.org/1.2.1/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/actor/DefaultActor.html#react(groovy.lang.Closure)).

It also has [`loop` methods](http://gpars.org/1.2.1/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/actor/DefaultActor.html#loop(groovy.lang.Closure,%20groovy.lang.Closure,%20java.lang.Runnable)). But neither has single `Closure`  as argument.

Can I be sure, that some of `loop` methods are called here?

Comment: Believe the constructor you're getting there is the single argument `Runnable`: http://gpars.org/1.2.1/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/actor/DefaultActor.html#loop(java.lang.Runnable) In groovy a trailing closure will be treated as the last argument, so in this case, the runnable code provided is the react closure itself.

Comment: There actually is a single-arg loop method in DefaultActor - https://github.com/vaclav/GPars/blob/master/src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/actor/DefaultActor.java#L112